# I don't understand the windings inside my power drill.

Tags: motor, ac, electromagnetism, universal-motor

I was curious about how my power drill worked and I disassembled it. I understand the general principles at work here but I don't understand why the winding is set up this way.

[image]

I assume running current through the solenoid in the center induces a magnetic field and causes the motor to spin. I notice the wires go parallel the axis of rotation (I assume to align the field correctly) so I'm not sure if you still refer to this as a solenoid.

[image: Core]

You can see there are 2 sets of winding. I am not sure why.

[image]

Not sure why the winding is configured this way either.

The trigger is a rheostat that goes from open -> ~15MOhm -> closed. The directional switch (not sure) I believe just changes which coil gets power. Since it's just AC and there's no AC-DC transformer I'm not sure how it would even matter which coil gets power since the field would presumably be flipping at the frequency of mains.

Comment: This is your basic `universal motor`.  Describing its operation is a job for reference materials - a question should only be posted after exhausting those.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The motor is a universal motor. It is so named because it can operate from either AC or DC power. The center rotating part is called the rotor. The outer stationary part is called the stator. The smaller diameter copper part on one end of the rotor is the commutator. Current flows through the stator windings and the commutator to the rotor windings. As the rotor moves, the commutator changes the connection of the rotor windings so that the magnetic field in the rotor is always at close to a right angle with the stator windings. That way the magnetic force keeps pulling the rotor around in a circle trying to align the rotor field with the stator field, but it can never catch up and just keeps on turning.

When a universal motor is operated from AC power, the current reverses 50 or 60 times per second depending on the power frequency. Since the current flows from the rotor to the stator, the current and magnetic field reverse in both parts at the same instant. That keeps the motor turning in the same direction even though the current keeps reversing.

To reverse the motor, the rotor winding connection is reversed with respect to the stator winding.

Since the universal motor has torque vs. speed characteristics similar to those of a DC motor, inserting a series resistance as with a rheostat works well as a method of speed control except for the heat generated in the resistor.

Comment: I agree with Chris Stratton, describing the operation is best left to reference materials, but I decided to post a quick explanation since you posted nice pictures and explained what you found by observation.

Comment: Excellent thank you for the writeup. I can search universal motors for a deeper understanding, I just didn't have any terminology to lookup. :)

Comment: `didn't have any terminology to lookup` .... how about doing a search for "electric motor parts"?